# migrate from Thunderbird to Evolution without re-downloading IMAP mails

Tags: thunderbird, evolution, mail, migration

I have about 3GB mails hold for offline usage in my thunderbird and it would take quite a while on a slow iinternet connection to re-download them all again in evolution.

Is there a way to install evolution and take the mail folders from the Thunderbird profile to fill the evolution mail folder?

Comment: Everyone is going the other direction.  Evolution to Thunderbird. Why are you considering migrating if I may ask?

Comment: I would like to use notbit as sendmail for a bitmessage ccount, but Thunderbird cannot [use a custom sendmail binary in Thunderbird](http://superuser.com/q/792835)

Answer (score 5):

Go to .thunderbird/Profiles/xxx.default/Mail/, and then to your mail folder.

There will be two types of files. Inbox.msf, and Inbox.  You need the file without the extension.

[image]

In Evolution,  go to mail window view and click File --> Import.

Select "import a single file" option when asked, and select the file (from above) you want to import and select a location to be imported.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Repeat for every archive that you have (if more than one).

Comment: I have no such large Inbox file in my thunderbird ImapMail folder. Maybe The storage foder structure has changed in Thundrbird 31?

Comment: I have 7GB in emails, and they are in multiple folders.  Do you have that?

Comment: yes, about 100 folders ;)

Comment: Unfortunately you have to do one at a time.

Comment: You can, just t try copying the mbox files into `~/.evolution/mail/local/Inbox.sbd/`.  Make sure that you copy first justto make sure it works.